# Using jQuery to foreach iframe src and get ID and action via functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm new to jQuery and JS. How can I rewrite these functions correctly using jQuery? I know it's standard JS which was working fine with the manual HTML markup but I now also need to go through page and find iframes with YouTube src and take ID and then recreate them with the first example markup.

I'm totally stuck. I think I have it more or less, but not sure where to go to now.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yurt5bb6/

First example uses my markup:

```
<div class="video-container">
   <div class="video-player" data-id="Cv_2mp3X868"></div>
</div>
```

Which works as I need, however I think now I need to foreach on load and create that same markup from iframe embeds the functions should be better.

Attempt:

```
function createThumb(id) {
    return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}

function createIframe() {
    var iframe = $("iframe");
    iframe.attr("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");
    iframe.attr("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.attr("id", "youtube-iframe");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // build video from default markup
    var defaultVideo = $(".video-player");
    $(defaultVideo).each(function (index, value){
        var p = $('<div></div>');
        p.innerHTML = createThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
        p.onclick = createIframe;
        v[n].appendChild(p);
    });

    // search for social embeds and recreate to our markup
    $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').each(function() {
        var loadedVideoURL = $('iframe').attr('src').match(/[^/]*$/)[0];
        console.log(loadedVideoURL);
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Sorry, still not clear as to what your issue or question is...

Comment: So in my fiddle i have the html markup  that takes the data-id (which is the youtube id) and uses the js functions to create the video and the custom thumbnail / button.... but thats when it is manually created in a template but i need to also search on page for any iframe youtube embeds, get the ID, recreate the markup (like the first exmaple) so they all act and function the same if you know what i mean...

Comment: Function the same as in the same src as well?

Comment: The initial loading part is normal JS and took from a tutorial so not sure how to re-write that using jQuery as think i should... i more or less need to redo the first part of the JS in a jQuery way, make the functions better so i can use it so i action the functions for the initial html markup video-player etc... but also be able to search for normal iframe embeds and write into the first example markup

Comment: the first example, basically makes a thumbnail of the video and overlays a play button so when clicked will then render and play the video

Comment: What's the reason this needs to be done like this?  Why not create the page without iframes in the first place?

Comment: Its an ecommerce system and although i place fied video within templates the content / staff editors add in editors with embeds codes so i need to find those and redo thats all.

Comment: You can simply use a jQuery `.replaceWith()` within your `.each()` and dynamically replace all iframes with divs.  The problem will re-rendering them since the page is already loaded.

Comment: I have tried to rewrite some best i can, ive updated question with my attempt...

Comment: Upon closer examination of your jsFiddle:  You're taking your working `div` player and dynamically turning it into an iframe... so now you're asking about how to take the iframe players and turn them into divs?

Comment: The first HTML with the video container is good (want to redo the JS for it but as it stands works) but i want to also search page for iframe youtube source,  get ID and then recreate so its like the first example so they are then all the same. Does that make sense? thanks for your help btw

Comment: My point was that your desired structure is being turned back into an iframe anyway.  Therefore, the answer below is doing a tremendous amount of unnecessary DOM manipulation... you're taking an iframe, rewriting it into a div, and then rewriting the div back into an iframe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to clean up the messy mix of native JS and jQuery and made some edits to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yurt5bb6/2/

Default function:

```
(function() {
    $.each($('.video-player'), function() {
        $(this).append(videoThumb($(this).data('id')));
        $(this).on('click', videoIframe);
    });

    $.each($('iframe'), function() {
        // Rebuild the given template
        var player = $('<div class="video-player">');

        // Strip youtube video id for data-id attribute
        var id = $(this).attr('src');
        id = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        player.attr('data-id', id);

        player.html(videoThumb(id));
        player.on('click', videoIframe);

        var videoContainer = $('<div class="video-container">');
        videoContainer.append(player);
        $(this).replaceWith(videoContainer);
    });
})();
```

Iframe render function:

```
function videoIframe() {
    var iframe = $('<iframe>');
    iframe.attr("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + $(this).attr('data-id') + "?autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");
    iframe.attr("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.addClass("youtube-iframe");
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append(iframe);
}
```

Also changed the CSS, made a class instead of id for youtube-iframe.

Comment: Ahh mate thats great, testing on the fiddle anyway! thanks for help me with that! really appreciate it!

Comment: You're taking an iframe, rewriting it into a div, and then rewriting the div back into an iframe... isn't a lot of this code in the middle superfluous?